# Saving and retrieving markers added by onMapLongClick

Tags: android, google-maps

I know i have asked a similar question like this before about saving the custom added markers to the map so when exiting the app and returning to the map the markers should still be there, but am training myself and find it hard to understand a few things

Here is my code for `SavePreferences()`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("listSize", markerList.size());

    for(int i = 0; i <markerList.size(); i++){
        editor.putFloat("lat"+i, (float) markerList.get(i).getPosition().latitude);
        editor.putFloat("long"+i, (float) markerList.get(i).getPosition().longitude);
        editor.putString("title"+i, markerList.get(i).getTitle());
    }
editor.commit(); 
}
```

And here is the `LoadPreferences()`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int size = sharedPreferences.getInt("listSize", 0);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    double lat = (double) sharedPreferences.getFloat("lat"+i,0);
    double longit = (double) sharedPreferences.getFloat("long"+i,0);
    String title = sharedPreferences.getString("title"+i,"NULL");

markerList.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, longit)).title(title)));
    }
}
}
```

and then i have this:

```
private List<Marker> markerList;
public MapActivity(){
    if(markerList == null){
        markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    }
}
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_googlemaps);
```

So all of the above i understand, but what i don't understand is how do i tell the app to save the `onMapLongClick` marker to the above code,  This is my `onMapLongClick` code:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
thePoint=point;

Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  .position(thePoint).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
     .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker)));
markerId = marker.getId(); //this is for the image taken by the camera intent to display full size image for marker.
```

So basically, how do I save `onMapLongClick` to shared preferences?

**EDIT**

This code I have here goes by the `onCreate` method?

```
LoadPreferences();
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
String label = data.getString("title");
int newLatitude = data.getInt("firstPoint");
int newLongitude = data.getInt("secondPoint");
```

Could some one please help me?